# How to Pass JSON Data into Express REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, express

I am creating a REST API using Node/Express and had a question regarding setting up the API and how to incorporate a JSON file into it. I have the following as an example of the JSON data I would like to look up and it includes an ID number, model and color:

{ 
    "1": {
        "car_model": "Ferrari",
        "color": "Silver"
    },
    "2": {
        "car_model": "Porsche",
        "color": "Green"
    },
    "3": {
        "car_model": "Camry",
        "color": "Blue"
    }
}

Now, I'd like to have the GET route return all the cars in the JSON list and return the ID, color and model. I'm not sure how to incorporate the JSON data into the requests (say it is located on my hard-drive at path/JSON)

I have the following code set up as the basics for the API:

```
// BASE SETUP
// =============================================================================

// call the packages we need
var express    = require('express');        // call express
var app        = express();                 // define our app using express
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;        // set our port


// ROUTES FOR OUR API
// =============================================================================
var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

// test route to make sure everything is working (accessed at GET http://localhost:8080/api)
router.get('/endpoint_get', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

router.post('/endpoint_post', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});


// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /endpoint.com
app.use('/endpoint.com/', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Not necessarily using this code, I would like some guidance or help from anyone or an example of how one would incorporate the JSON data (from some random file) into the HTTP requests. Thank you

Comment: I believe you could just require it in that file. like const json = require("./jsonFile"). then use it how you need

Comment: That would work if you do not want to write any updates to disk

Comment: Thanks Roger, so if I wanted to access it from a path on my desktop say, I just put that as the paramter for require? For example: const json = require("Desktop/jsonFile") or does it have it to be in the project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const jsonDoc = require('../Desktop/jsonDoc.json');// top of file...


router.get('/endpoint_get', function(req, res) {
try{
let jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonDoc) /*{ "1": { "car_model": "Ferrari", "color": "Silver" }, "2": { "car_model": "Porsche", "color": "Green" }, "3": { "car_model": "Camry", "color": "Blue" } }*/
console.log(jsonObj)

    res.json({
        message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!',
        jsonDoc:JSON.stringify(jsonObj) 
     });   
/* returns {
  "message": "hooray! welcome to our api!",
  "jsonDoc": { "1": { "car_model": "Ferrari", "color": "Silver" }, "2": { "car_model": "Porsche", "color": "Green" }, "3": { "car_model": "Camry", "color": "Blue" } }
}*/

}catch(error){ /* now if anything above fails a error code can be returned to the caller and debug info can be sent to the developer*/
console.trace(error);// trace out the error.
res.sendStatus(500)// return error code to user.
}
    });
```

Comment: Ok - and after using stringify, would it make sense to use some sort of regex or parse function to breakout the data in the JSON file (this is what I ultimately want to accomplish)? The file has an id, car type and color but I want to get that specific data from the JSON file

Comment: I would manipulate the data before the stringify and you would use JSON.parse(JSONfile)  this will allow you to use dot notation to change the objects key/value pairs.

Comment: Also,  use a try catch in your route. Right now your route will hang if something fails.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do this or what you mean more specifically?

Comment: Thanks very much. You're review was already very helpful but I just didn't quite follow the try/catch (that felt like it could be a rabbithole where I spend a lot of time but was sort of besides my main purpose, so I just wanted to get some more specific detail on what you meant).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use node fs (filesystem).

One option is to convert your endpoint to an async function.

On each request open the file with fs.open(). Depending on your requirements, either read the entire file or provide an offset to read from.

Then parse the data with `JSON.parse()`, format and return.

---

Another option would be to do all the above steps on startup, saving the contents of the file to some sort of store. Then you can bypass the slow reading from disk in the request handling.

Here is some example code from node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_event_open). I would recommend having a look at the different options.

I would also recommend using the methods that return a promise, (or promisify the callbacks). That way you code that accesses it can have a clean ordering to it.

```js
fs.open('/open/some/file.txt', 'r', (err, fd) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.fstat(fd, (err, stat) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    // use stat

    // always close the file descriptor!
    fs.close(fd, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this  seems like its a bit complicated for this task (i.e. using fs) but perhaps thats just whats' needed. I will review the Node docs and see what else there is.